# Data is automatically stored more than once in an arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am creating an arraylist from my database in android for use in adapter of recycler view:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.homeRecycler);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
ArrayList<StocksforHome> stockList = new ArrayList<>();
DbInteract interact = new DbInteract(getContext());
Cursor cursor = interact.readtable();
HomeFragmentAdapter homeFragmentAdapter = new HomeFragmentAdapter(stockList, getContext());
GetHomeData getHomeData = new GetHomeData(getContext(),homeFragmentAdapter);
int i=0;
stockList.clear();
while(cursor.moveToNext())
{
    StocksforHome temp = new StocksforHome();
    temp.stock = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(eventDBcontract.ListofItem.columnsym));
    stockList.add(temp);
}
homeFragmentAdapter.addall(stockList);
Log.d(tag,String.valueOf(stockList.size()) + " " + String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(homeFragmentAdapter);
```

There is only one data in database but still the size of arraylist is 2. I checked that the extra data is duplicate of first one.
Log report:

```
D/HomeFragment: 2 1
```

I have made a custom adapter. Its addall method is:

```
 public void addall(ArrayList<StocksforHome> more)
{
    stockArrayList.addAll(more);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: You initialize the adapter by passing a list, and then you add elements without clearing the list

Comment: clear your list `stockArrayList` inside `addall` method

Comment: doing that makes stockarraylist empty. nothing displayed in view. yes, i did it before adding more

Comment: before adding `more` list to your `stockArrayList.addAll(more);` clear your  `stockArrayList.addAll(more);`

Comment: yes, thats what i did.

Comment: I think that `stockArrayList` and `stockList` refer to same collection, so you just add the list into itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `stockList` in adapter and `stockList` in code snippet are the same reference, in result items are added twice. To fix this adapter needs his own instance of `List`.

First add:

```
stockList.add(temp);
```

Second add:

```
homeFragmentAdapter.addall(stockList);
```

**Fix adapter like this:**

```
HomeFragmentAdapter {

    private final List<StocksforHome> stockList = new Arraylist<>();

    public HomeFragmentAdapter(Context context) {
    }

    public void addall(List<StocksforHome> more) {
        stockList.clear();
        stockList.addAll(more);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.homeRecycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    ArrayList<StocksforHome> stockList = new ArrayList<>();
    DbInteract interact = new DbInteract(getContext());
    Cursor cursor = interact.readtable();
    HomeFragmentAdapter homeFragmentAdapter;
    GetHomeData getHomeData = new GetHomeData(getContext(), homeFragmentAdapter);
    int i = 0;
    // clear and add data in your code 
    stockList.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        StocksforHome temp = new StocksforHome();
        temp.stock = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(eventDBcontract.ListofItem.columnsym));
        stockList.add(temp);
    }
    if (homeFragmentAdapter == null) {
        homeFragmentAdapter = new HomeFragmentAdapter(stockList, getContext());

        Log.d(tag, String.valueOf(stockList.size()) + " " + String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(homeFragmentAdapter);
    } else {
        // add all data 
        homeFragmentAdapter.addall(stockList);
    }
```

Firstly , getting data

Secondly , setting it to the adapter

```
homeFragmentAdapter = new HomeFragmentAdapter(stockList, getContext());
```

And refresh data in your code

```
homeFragmentAdapter.addall(stockList);
```